# Access django database on postgresql from independent python script

Tags: python, django, database

I have a website built with django and postgresql.
each user (user in django Auth system) on the website have many account models (and other models) .

An app running on windows-python based need to access (read/write) data from the database.
Each app is associated with a specific user.

my questions:

1. can an app access only specific user data? the account model have an attribute of user so it filter based on that, how can it restrict external app access?
2. what is the proper way to read / write from database? can I somehow use the django models as the website do?

Comment: Django has DB functionalities: so you write Python classes for your tables and use instances in your app. Django handles the rest. [Here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-postgresql-django) is an in-depth and easy to follow tutorial on how to use Django+PG.

Comment: this is not my question. I already have it all running and set. I want to access data from outside django+pg server. from an app running on Android/windows client.

Comment: First option is create an API in Django (there are core modules for that as well). Second option, connect to the DB using the full URL, e.g. `postgresql://user:passwd@host/mydatabase`.

Comment: Second option give admin access to DB, right ?

Comment: `can an app access only specific user data?` Usually, if the app connects directly to the database, you can't give a user access to only their data. SQL does have permissions, but those permissions are very broad. You wouldn't be able to give a user access to edit only part of a table, for example. Typically you would use an application server, like Django, to implement access control for individual users, and not allow users to connect directly to the database.

Comment: @NickODell this is the question, how, using django, I can access the database user wise from an extertnal app running outside the server.?

Comment: maybe management commands can help. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/custom-django-management-commands/

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to build an API layer to exchange data between your Django and your externals. Django rest framework provides a really simply solution to add a REST layer to your app that is also reusable with any other external.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

With this approach you centralize and abstract the direct database manipulation in Django, avoiding any external operation that may break it's consistency (for example with an alter table).

Comment: And this can have both read/write access using a username (/token) ?

Comment: Yes sure. Generally you will create API Views o r Viewsets with common actions: get for retrieve and Post, Put, Patch, Delete for write.
For everything you could specify permissions required: AllowAny, IsAuthenticated, etc. see:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/
For tokenization in the backend i use simple-jwt: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/